# Bayesian statistics notation: "$P(\text{event}|x)$" vs "$P(\text{event}|\theta, x)$"

Tags: statistics, notation, proof-explanation, statistical-inference, bayesian

Now I am  new to the subject so, having some rotational problems. My issues are -

1. What is the meaning of $P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|x) $ and $P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|\theta, x)$ or what are the differences between these two?
2. Why $ P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|\theta, x)= \theta$? Is it because, actually $ P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|\theta, x)= p(\theta)$  but in this case,  the probability of  $\theta $  is $\theta$, i.e. $p(\theta)=\theta$ ?

Let me clarify what I am talking about.

The problem on page $22$ of the text of [Introduction to Bayesian Statistics by Brendon J. Brewer](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ebrewer/stats331.pdf) is written as following  -

> After moving to Auckland, I decided that I would take the bus to work
> each day. However, I wasn’t very confident with the bus system in my
> new city, so for the first week I just took the first bus that came
> along and was heading in the right direction, towards the city. In the
> first week, I caught 5 morning buses. Of these 5 buses, two of them
> took me to the right place, while three of them took me far from work,
> leaving me with an extra 20 minute walk. Given this information, I
> would like to try to infer the proportion of the buses that are "good", that would take me right
> to campus. Let us call this fraction $\theta$ and we will infer $\theta$ using the Bayesian framework.

Here, $\theta =2/5.$

For example, look the following image -

[image]

Recall that, if there are $N$ repetitions of a "random experiment" and the "success"
probability is $\theta$ at each repetition, then the number of "successes" $x$. To get the likelihoods, we need to think about the properties of our experiment. In particular, we should imagine that we knew the value of $\theta$  and were trying to predict what experimental outcome (data) would occur. Ultimately, we want to find the probability of our actual data set (2 out of the 5 buses were "good"), for all of our possible $\theta$ values.

$P(\theta|x)$ is the posterior probability. It describes $\textbf{how certain or confident we
are that hypothesis $\theta$ is true, given that}$ we have observed data $x$.

Calculating posterior probabilities is the main goal of Bayesian statistics!

$P(\theta)$ is the prior probability, which describes $\textbf{how sure we were that}$ $\theta$ was true,
before we observed the data $x$.

$P(x|\theta)$ is the likelihood. $\textbf{If you were to assume that $\theta$ is true, this is the
probability}$ that you would have observed data $x$.

$P(x)$ is the marginal likelihood. This is the probability that you would have observed data $x$, whether $\theta$ is true or not.

So, $P (\theta|x) = \frac{P (\theta) P(x|\theta)}{P (x)}$

The following part is an excerpt from the same text -

> In the Bayesian framework, our predictions are always in the form of
> probabilities or (later) probability distributions. They are usually
> calculated in three stages.
>
> First, you pretend you actually know the true value of the parameters,
> and calculate the probability based on that assumption.
>
> Then, you do this for all possible values of the parameter $\theta$
> (alternatively, you can calculate the probability as a function of
> $\theta$).
>
> Finally, you combine all of these probabilities in a particular way to
> get one final probability which tells you how confident you are of
> your prediction.
>
> Suppose we knew the true value of $\theta$ was $0.3$. Then, we would
> know the probability of catching the right bus tomorrow is $0.3$. If
> we knew the true value of $\theta$ was $0.4$, we would say the
> probability of catching the right bus tomorrow is 0.4.
>
> The problem is, we don’t know what the true value is. We only have the
> posterior distribution. Luckily, the sum rule of probability (combined
> with the product rule) can help us out.
>
> We are interested in whether I will get the good bus tomorrow. There
> are $11$ different ways that can happen. Either $\theta=0$ and I get
> the good bus, or $\theta=0.1$ and I get the good bus, or $\theta=0.2$
> and I get the good bus, and so on. These 11 ways are all mutually
> exclusive. That is, only one of them can be true (since $\theta$ is
> actually just a single number).
>
> Mathematically, we can obtain the posterior probability of catching
> the good bus tomorrow using the sum rule: $$P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|x) = \sum_{\theta} p(\theta|x) \times P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|\theta, x) $$$$=  \sum_{\theta} p(\theta|x) \times \theta$$
>
> This says that the total probability for a good bus tomorrow (given
> the data, i.e. using the posterior distribution and not the prior
> distribution) is given by
>
> 1. going through each possible $\theta$ value,
> 2. working out the probability assuming the $\theta$ value you are considering is true, multiplying by the probability (given the data)
>    this $\theta$ value is actually true,
> 3. and summing.
>
> In this particular problem, because $P\text{(good bus  tomorrow}|\theta, x) = θ$, it just so happens that the probability for
> tomorrow is the expectation value of $\theta$ using the posterior
> distribution.
>
> To three decimal places, the result for the probability tomorrow is
> $0.429$. Interestingly, this is not equal to $2/5 = 0.4$.

Comment: On (2) $p(\theta)$ is not $\theta$: the box suggests the prior $p(\theta)=\frac1 {11} \approx 0.0909$ for each of the $11$ suggested possible values of $\theta$

Comment: You say:
> Here $\theta = 2/5$.
That's not accurate, rather we do not know what $\theta$ is. We observe $x$ however, which is that 2 out of 5 buses were good.

Answer (score 3):

$P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|x)$ is the probability of getting on a good bus tomorrow given the data $x$ you've already observed, which in this example is that 2 out of 5 buses were good.

$P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|\theta, x)$ is the probability of getting on a good bus tomorrow given that you already know exactly what $\theta$ and $x$ are. Here we treat $\theta$ and $x$ as fixed and known, so if you already know $\theta$, then the probability of catching a good bus tomorrow is simply $\theta$. Hence, $P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|\theta, x) = \theta$.

The probability of catching a good bus on any given day is $\theta$. While, we don't actually know what $\theta$ is, we have probabilities for what we think $\theta$ is before ever coming to Auckland, which we denote by $p(\theta)$. In this example, $p(\theta) = 1/11$, i.e. each possible $\theta$ is equally likely. This can be confusing since both $\theta$ and $p(\theta)$ are probabilities--the difference being that $p(\theta)$ is a "probability distribution" over $\theta$.

What you observe is the data $x$, and you want to figure out: $P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|x)$. That's where the math comes in:

$$\begin{align}
P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|x) &= \sum_{\theta} p(\theta|x) \times P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|\theta, x) \\
&= \sum_{\theta} p(\theta|x) \times \theta \\
&= E[\theta | x]
\end{align}$$

The probability of catching a good bus tomorrow is whatever you expect $\theta$ to be on average given what you've observed $x$.
The new probability distribution over $\theta$ given the data $x$ you've observed is denoted by $p(\theta|x)$.

Comment: Why $P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|x) = \sum_{\theta} p(\theta|x) $ is not enough,  why we need to multiply $ p(\theta|x)$ by $P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|\theta, x)$ in the sum $\sum_{\theta}$?.

Comment: @Andrew To quickly see why that is not enough, notice that for any $x$ we have: $\sum_{\theta} p(\theta|x) = 1$.  (This all has to do with the [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).)  The idea here is the probability of a good bus tomorrow is just the expected value of $\theta$ (given the information we have today $x$).  The expected value of $\theta$ is an average of all possible $\theta$'s weighted by their probabilities.

Comment: Failed to see, could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @Andrew Sure, on why $\sum_{\theta} p(\theta|x) = 1$?

Comment: No that is clear, but  why we need to multiply $ p(\theta|x)$ by $P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|\theta, x)$ in the sum $\sum_{\theta}$..

Comment: @Andrew In your example there are $11$ different possibilities: $\theta=0,\, .1, \, .2\ldots$., so what's the probability of a good bus arriving tomorrow? Well, with probability $p(\theta=0|x)$ there is $0$ probability of a good bus arriving tomorrow. With probability $p(\theta=.1|x)$ there is a $.1$ chance of a good bus arriving tomorrow. With probability $p(\theta=.2|x)$ there is a $.2$ chance of a good bus arriving tomorrow. The probability that a good bus arrives tomorrow is the sum of $\theta$ weighted by $p(\theta|x)$. (This is all explained by the Law of Total Probability.)

Comment: So, $p(\theta|x)$ is just a weight? I mean why we just multiplied a weight? What is the reason? This weight multiplying does not seem to have any relation with Bayesian Theorem, also why posterior probability $p(\theta|x)$  has become a weight instead $P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|\theta, x)$?

Comment: @Andrew So, you're asking about where this expression comes from:
$$P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|x) = \sum_{\theta} p(\theta|x) \times P(\text{good bus tomorrow}|\theta, x)$$
That expression directly follows from the [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). I'm trying (but not succeeding) to provide intuitions for how this law holds within your example. Yes, we can think of $p(\theta|x)$ as a weight for different possible values of $\theta$. Yes, this is not about the Bayesian Theorem, this is about the Law of Total Probability.

Comment: All I can do (given that my intuition doesn't make sense to you for this particular expression) is tell you what theorem/law is being applied. You're going to have to read about that theorem/law (the Law of Total Probability) and convince yourself it makes sense. I'm happy to answer questions about that law and how it is being applied here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834807/how-p-thetax-and-p-textgood-bus-tomorrow-theta-x-are-independent